# How to print to a HP Photosmart C4599 printer from Sierra?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, printing

I am desperately trying to print from my MacbookPro running Sierra to a HP Phtosmart C4599.

Does anyone have any idea? Is there a solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @nohillside Thank you for your message. I linked my computer to the printer with the wire, and my computer isn’t detecting the latter. It used to work with my McBookAir, which was much younger than my current computer.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details. By wire I assume "USB cable", right? Did you try a different cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the driver doesn't get installed automatically, it can be downloaded from [HP's website](https://support.hp.com/ch-de/drivers/selfservice/hp-photosmart-c4500-all-in-one-printer-series/3575173) -> [HPPrinterDrivers5.1.dmg](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software12/HP_Quick_Start/osx/Applications/ASU/HPPrinterDrivers5.1.dmg)